# PHP Temp file on Windows

Tags: php

I use PHP image uplaod script. It only put file 4 or 5 kb.

php58E.tmp (5 KB)

I'm not uploading 60kb image, but the 5 kb hanging. This issue windows?

Comment: You should look at the Network Panel of the Chrome Dev Tools/Firebug Console to find more details about what went wrong, and post it here as well.

Comment: Thank you reply message. Console is blank. Not seems problem.

Comment: One step further is to look at the exact entry in the network panel. Is it timing out? Is it hitting the right URL? What response code is being returned?

Comment: Just waiting.. I'm refresh and internal error.

Comment: Where you got that script? Could it be some "demo-like" restriction in the script's config file?

Comment: Is free. http://www.4plcr.com/IntSys/scripts/image_upload_with_resize.zip

Comment: I not upload 8kb, 10kb or 20kb, Only 5kb accept. Php temp not write 10kb image file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change php image upload size in php.ini

xampp/php/php.ini

upload_max_size
```

Comment: My upload_max_filesize = 100M, upload_max_size not defined

Comment: By default is 2MB, it's hihg unlikely it has been set to a such low value. 5kb, really?

Comment: Yes, 4kb 5kb 6kb files fast upload. 9kb, 10kb or 60kb images waiting and timeout.